# How to handle if client request by GET method which is originally POST in controller in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/abc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public class TestController {
    .....

}
```

what if user will request `/abc` as `GET` Method how i can Handle Request?

Answer (score 0):

You will get an exception:

```
Request method 'GET' not supported
```

You can support multiple method (GET,POST...) by remove method in annotation.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/abc")
```